# WP7 navigate back from other application automatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, automation, navigation, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to automate testing of WP7 apps. In my app, one functionality is CALL; ie; the page changes to WP's phone call page. While testing I want it to automatically come back from the phone call page to simulate a "back" press. I know we can use navigation service to perform back - press however I want to use the back-press on a different page which is not under my control(ie; default phone call page). Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, Current that is not supported in the WP7.
Even if any hacks make it possible also, your application doesn't meet the certification requirements.
So no point, in making this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Certification is not a problem as this is just for automated testing and will not be a part of final build.